# PHP Date returning in MySQL Db as 0000-00-00 00:00

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

there are a few answers for this but they all seem to have different solutions based on the application.

In my PHP code I have a for loop creating the variables for use in an HTML select:

```
 $today_select = new DateTime();
 $day1 = new DateTime();
 $day1_value = $day1->format('Y/m/d');

 for($i = 2; $i < 8; $i++) {
 ${'day' . $i} = $today_select->modify('+1 day');
 ${'day' . $i . '_select'} = ${'day' . $i}->format('l, jS F Y');
 ${'day' . $i . '_value'} = ${'day' . $i}->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
 }
```

This loop declares the variables and sets the date as the value, incrementing through for the week.

I then have a select for the dates:

```
 <select name="nd_date" id="nd_date">
 <option value="'.$day1_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' selected>Today      '.$day1_value.'</option>
 <option value="'.$day2_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' >Tomorrow'.$day2_value.'</option>
 <option value="'.$day3_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' >'.$day3_select.' '.$day3_value.'</option>
 <option value="'.$day4_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' >'.$day4_select.' '.$day4_value.'</option>
 <option value="'.$day5_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' >'.$day5_select.' '.$day5_value.'</option>
 <option value="'.$day6_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' >'.$day6_select.' '.$day6_value.'</option>
 <option value="'.$day7_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' >'.$day7_select.' '.$day7_value.'</option>
 </select>
```

This assigns the value to $nd_delivery_date which  is then written to the database. The date in the database has been of both Date and Datetime variety and not worked for either.

I have tried converting strtodate in the for loop, I have also tried using date rather than datetime in the for loop and no joy.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it wrong to put two values on the same option?

Comment: It works for all the other selects I have - one is declaring the select value, and one is declaring the variable value.

Comment: You can only have one `value` attribute on an option element in HTML... it isn't possible for one option to have two values.

Comment: Wait where is the database code...? Is it getting 0000-00-00 from db or is it setting 0000-00-00 to db?

Comment: Jon - how come this is working then? <option value="MP16" value = '.($nd_tariff == '').'>Mail Pack by 17.30</option>
This sets the variable nd_tariff to whatever is selected and inputs it into the database, I dispute your claim as I have a plethora of selects doing this.

Comment: Mike Shi - it is setting to 0000-00-00 not getting

Comment: Your browser is probably taking the last `value` attribute in each `<option>`, but this is behaviour is not defined in the standard.

Comment: @Daffy That code is dangerous. You must only declare one value attribute, and it should be equal to the value of that option. You should not use the second value attribute.

Comment: @Arphrial what is dangerous about it? TBF i am not a developer, simply copying how things have been done by the people who developed the site. To me it is doing what I want it to do, but if it is dangerous I'd like to know the potential effects!

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` columns in MySQL are formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`, whilst `DATETIME` columns are formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` ([MySql Datetime Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html))

Your DateTime value variables are formatting the datetime to `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`

I'd first suggest changing your `\`s to `-`s in your date.

Edit:

Also, as shown in the comments, you should not be using multiple `value` attributes in one `<option>`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the second value, but I'd suggest you remove it!

Second Edit:

Your `$day1` variables, compared to `$day2-7` are also different:

```
 $day1_value = $day1->format('Y/m/d');
```

For all other days, your `$day{X}_value` variables are set to a different date format.
I would recommend you just set one pattern as a variable at the top of your code and use that.

E.g.

```
$datetime_pattern = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
...
$day1_value = $day1->format($datetime_pattern);
...
${'day' . $i . '_value'} = ${'day' . $i)->format($datetime_pattern);
```

Comment: I've done that - format('Y-m-d H:i:s') - No dice. I'm sure this is a formatting issue, just a matter of weedling out the little blighter.

Comment: I've done the datetime pattern thing - i had also standardised before that, still nothing. like the idea of passing that as a variable though, very helpful

Comment: Can you show your raw HTML source of the form? After PHP has processed it.

Comment: <select name="nd_date" id="nd_date">
<option value="2014-01-10 09:31:40" value=1 selected>Today 2014-01-10 09:31:40</option>
<option value="2014-01-11 09:31:40" value=1 >Tomorrow2014-01-11 09:31:40</option>
<option value="2014-01-12 09:31:40" value=1 >Sunday, 12th January 2014 2014-01-12 09:31:40</option>
<option value="2014-01-13 09:31:40" value=1 >Monday, 13th January 2014 2014-01-13 09:31:40</option>
<option value="2014-01-14 09:31:40" value=1 >Tuesday, 14th January 2014 2014-01-14 09:31:40</option>
and so on

Comment: Worth pointing out that the source threw me as the value=1 clearly wasn't what I expected to see. Investigating now, but the 2 values thing wasn't being repeated anywhere but in my code. Slap my head could come to mind right now.... will report back in 5 mins when I've cleared it all up

Answer (score 0):

So, above we learned that it was a very bad idea to have to values setting in the option, bad code and incorrectly perceived to me to be doing the job of assigning the values to the variable.

What actually sets the value to the variable?

```
 <select name="nd_date" id="nd_date">
  <option value="'.$day1_value.'" value='.($nd_delivery_date == '').' selected>Today      '.$day1_value.'</option>
```

The select name! So this was called nd_date whilst i'm actually caring about setting the value to the variable of nd_delivery_date.

```
  <select name="nd_delivery_date" id="nd_date">
  <option value="'.$day1_value.'" selected>Today'.$day1_value.'</option>
```

My code was horribly wrong and the pitfalls of copying code you don't fully understand are highlighted here!